# GitLab's Docker container refuses to accept large LFS files

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

I have a large binary file which I want to track through GitLab, I have my docker compose file written as below:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: '[domain]'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url '[domain]'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '4096m'
```

GitLab runs fine ontop of a machine installed with Debian. When uploading the file tracked via Git LFS it gives me the following error after upload about 1.5Gs everytime:

```
Uploading LFS objects:  78% (7/9), 1.3 GB | 5.9 MB/s, done.
LFS: Put "https://[domain].com/x.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/": read tcp x:51042->y:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
LFS: Put "https://[domain].com/x.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/": read tcp x:51042->y:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Not sure why this behavior is happening, any help appreciated.